# Wrap_contents or DP for ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I see some people user the exact dp measurements for Imageview width and height in their layout while some others use wrap_contant.

Wrap_content would take the image size and display it accordingly. So if it is 60px by 60px then it will look smaller on high density screen and larger on low density screen.

While using the exact dp measurements lets say 60 dp, will make it look of the same size on all the screens.

As a result, shouldn't we be using the exact measurements all the time and not wrap_content? Am I missing something here

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you use wrap_content, then the system will choose the resource from the appropriate resource folder depending on the screen density (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc) and will use the px dimension of that resource. Since the screen density resource folders (mdpi, hdpi, etc) can each apply to various screen densities (ie, mdpi is ~160dpi, but can be a bit less or a bit more before hitting the next density), this means that the image may change size slightly on different screens. If you specify the actual dp value for height and width, then you ensure the image will scale to maintain the same physical size on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `wrap_content` is too small than what you want, or too big than what you want
so you can give exact measurements

If you want to make sure your exact measurements support multiple screen sizes, you can put them inside a `dimens` file which then loads according to the correct screen size

look into [Support Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

if for example you create a folder calld `"values-sw600dp"` 
and put a dimen file in it, and have a property

```
<dimen name="imageSizeWidth">60dp</dimen>
```

And your image will be defined as follows

```
<ImageView 
   android:layout_width="@dimen/imageSizeWidth"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/imageSizeWidth"

/>
```

Then it will be loaded, if the device matches the description "at least 600dp scree width"
this is providing there are other values folders in your resources.

If you don't have any other values folders, then this will be loaded by default

Comment: Thank you but I am not asking about how to use exact measurements on different devices. I am asking when would someone use wrap contents and not exact measurements. Like I explained above, wrapcontent would look different on different devices depending on densities , right?